# Pygame coding enemy respawn

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to figure out how to add enemy respawns in my game when the enemy dies it basically goes invisible and you can still shoot it. I tried different types of code and looked to different articles for an answer but could not find anything. Also need help on finding a way to end the game may be on a timer. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it!

```
    import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('bullet.wav')
hitSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('hit.wav')

music = pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

score = 0


def enemy(param, param1, param2, param3, param4):
    pass


goblins = [enemy(100, 410, 64, 64, 450)]


class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.standing = True
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if not (self.standing):
            if self.left:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)
        # pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

    def hit(self):
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 410
        self.walkCount = 0
        font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 100)
        text = font1.render('-5', 1, (255, 0, 0))
        win.blit(text, (250 - (text.get_width() / 2), 200))
        pygame.display.update()
        i = 0
        while i < 200:
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            i += 1
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    i = 201
                    pygame.quit()


class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)


class enemy(object):
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1E.png'), pygame.image.load('R2E.png'), pygame.image.load('R3E.png'),
                 pygame.image.load('R4E.png'), pygame.image.load('R5E.png'), pygame.image.load('R6E.png'),
                 pygame.image.load('R7E.png'), pygame.image.load('R8E.png'), pygame.image.load('R9E.png'),
                 pygame.image.load('R10E.png'), pygame.image.load('R11E.png')]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1E.png'), pygame.image.load('L2E.png'), pygame.image.load('L3E.png'),
                pygame.image.load('L4E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'), pygame.image.load('L6E.png'),
                pygame.image.load('L7E.png'), pygame.image.load('L8E.png'), pygame.image.load('L9E.png'),
                pygame.image.load('L10E.png'), pygame.image.load('L11E.png')]

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
        self.health = 10
        self.visible = True

    def draw(self, win):
        self.move()
        if self.visible:
            if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33:
                self.walkCount = 0

            if self.vel > 0:
                win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1

            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50, 10))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 128, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
            # pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0

    def hit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
            self.health -= 1
        else:
            self.visible = False
        print('hit')


def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    text = font.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(text, (350, 10))
    man.draw(win)
    goblins.draw(win)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()


# mainloop
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30, True)
man = player(200, 410, 64, 64)
goblins = enemy(100, 410, 64, 64, 450)
shootLoop = 0
bullets = []
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    if goblins.visible == True:
        if man.hitbox[1] < goblins.hitbox[1] + goblins.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > goblins.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > goblins.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < goblins.hitbox[0] + goblins.hitbox[2]:
                man.hit()
                score -= 5

    if shootLoop > 0:
        shootLoop += 1
    if shootLoop > 3:
        shootLoop = 0

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if goblins:
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < goblins[0].hitbox[1] + goblins[0].hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > \
                    goblins[0].hitbox[
                        1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > goblins[0].hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < goblins[0].hitbox[0] + \
                        goblins[0].hitbox[2]:
                    hitSound.play()
                    goblins[0].hit()
                    score += 1
                    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

            if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x += bullet.vel
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and shootLoop == 0:
        bulletSound.play()
        if man.left:
            facing = -1
        else:
            facing = 1
                 
        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(
                projectile(round(man.x + man.width // 2), round(man.y + man.height // 2), 6, (0, 0, 0), facing))
        if enemy.health < 0:
            goblins.remove(0)
        shootLoop = 1

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
    else:
        man.standing = True
        man.walkCount = 0

    if not (man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10
    if not goblins:
        goblins.append(enemy(100, 410, 64, 64, 450))

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: To help us help you, make this into a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I looked through your code but i cant spot where you have deleted the goblin object, which is probably why the enemy is invincible. What i suggest is you make a list for enemies. In your case you only have one enemy, but  doing this allows you to have multiple enemies as well.

```
goblins = [enemy(100, 410, 64, 64, 450)]
```

Now you have to change the collision detection as well to use the `goblins` list instead of the `goblin` object.

```
if goblins:
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < goblins[0].hitbox[1] + goblins[0].hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > goblins[0].hitbox[
                1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > goblins[0].hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < goblins[0].hitbox[0] + \
                        goblins[0].hitbox[2]:
                    hitSound.play()
                    goblins[0].hit()
                    score += 1
                    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
```

You have to do this for the collision  detection of player and enemy as well and anywhere else you might have used goblin, obviously.

Now that we have enemy in a list, if the enemy dies we can remove the enemy from the list.

```
if enemy.health < 1:
    goblins.remove(0)
```

Then just put the following somewhere in the main loop so that if there are no enemies in the list, it adds one.

```
if not goblins:
    goblins.append(enemy(100, 410, 64, 64, 450))
```

Comment: I will try this and answer ASAP I did not expect someone to answer this quickly lol sorry for not replying faster thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. If it didn't work then just let me know and we will try and figure out the problem.

Comment: Doing this makesmy game have a black screen with no drawing.

Comment: if enemy.health < 1:
AttributeError: type object 'enemy' has no attribute 'health'

Comment: Thats strange, enemy does have attribute health. Try and make sure you have spelled everything correct.

Comment: everything looks correct to me, maybe wrong placement

Comment: Hmm, can you edit the question and replace your old code with the new one so i can see it.